Show that the probability of a team winning a tournament increases as it plays more games, subject to $P(win) > 0.5$ for each game.
Suppose two teams play a total of $2k + 1$ $(k \geq 0)$ games out of which whoever gets the majority of wins win. Further suppose that team $A$ has a wins each game with a probability $p$ (independent of other games). If $P_{n}$ is the probability that team $A$ wins, show that: $$P_{2k+1} > P_{2k-1} \iff p > 0.5.$$

Team $A$ wins the series of $n = 2k+1 \ (k \geq 0)$ games if and only if it is the first to win $k+1$ games.
To win $k+1$ games, $A$ wins the $(k+j)^\text{th}$ game and any $k$ out of $(k+j-1)$ of the previously played games for some $j \in \{0,1, \cdots, k\}$. This takes into consideration that once $k+1$ games are won by a team, no more games will be played (or even if played, it won't result in the other team's win). 
Mathematically, this turns out to be: 
$$P_{2k+1} = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{k} {k+j \choose j} p^{k+1} (1-p)^j.$$
We additionally have $$\displaystyle \begin{align} P_{2k + 1} - P_{2k - 1} &= \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} \ \left[ p{k+j \choose j} - {k+j-1 \choose j} \right] p^{k} (1-p)^j + {2k \choose k} p^{k+1} (1-p)^k \\ &= \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} \ {k+j-1 \choose j} \left( p + \frac{pj}{k} - 1 \right) p^{k} (1-p)^j + {2k \choose k} p^{k+1} (1-p)^k \\ &\lesseqgtr \ 0 \quad \text{..but when?} \end{align}$$
I simulated using R and it turns out that $P_{2k+1} \oplus P_{2k-1} \iff p \oplus 0.5$ for $\oplus \in \{<,>,=\}$. How do I show that?

Defining $q=1-p$, and applying the identity:
$$\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r}+\binom{n-1}{r-1},$$
to $\binom{k+j}{j}$, after some calculation, we obtain
$$P_{2k+1}=p^{k+1}+\left [ p(P_{2k-1}-p^k)+ \binom{2k-1}{k}p^{k+1}q^k\right ]+\left [ q \left (P_{2k+1}-\binom{2k}{k}p^{k+1}q^k \right) \right ].$$
This gives
$$p(P_{2k+1}-P_{2k-1})=\binom{2k-1}{k}p^{k+1}q^k - q\binom{2k}{k}p^{k+1}q^k,$$
which can be further simplified to
$$P_{2k+1}-P_{2k-1}=p^{k}q^k\binom{2k-1}{k}  \underbrace{(1-2q)}_{2p-1} ,$$
showing the desired result
$$ P_{2k+1}-P_{2k-1}>0 \Leftrightarrow p>\frac12.$$

I'll have to write it on a piece of paper and see. Thanks.

@adamsmaple You are welcome! Let me know if more clarification is needed.
